# Different url path than pk in Django Generic View

Tags: django, django-urls, django-generic-views, detailview

I am using DetailView to display a template with the information about my object from my model.
I used int:pk as the path for my object, but now I want to access the view from something like detail/XX-ABC (where XX-ABC stands for a unique field from my model). I didn't find a way to pass this slug and display the object.

```
path(r'detail/<int:pk>/', views.DetailClientsView.as_view(template_name='clients/clients_details.html',
                                                           context_object_name='client'),name='details_client'),
```

And this is my View.

```
class DetailClientsView(DetailView, UpdateView):
model = Clients
form_class = InspectionForm
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('search:search')
```

Comment: YOu name it `slug`, or you specify the slug in the `slug_url_kwarg`.

Comment: I tried to add slug_url_kwarg in my view but it raised "Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field." when I changed the path in 'detail/<slug:my_field_from_model>/'

Comment: you have two parameters `slug_url_kwarg` which is the name of the slug in the **`path(..)`**, and `slug_field`, which is the name of the slug field in your model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you, I missed to use slug_field. It helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a slug in the url named `slug`:

```
path(
    'detail/<slug:slug>/',
    views.DetailClientsView.as_view(
        template_name='clients/clients_details.html',
        context_object_name='client'
    ),
    name='details_client'
),
```

or you can give it another name, for example:

```
path(
    'detail/<slug:client_slug>/',
    views.DetailClientsView.as_view(
        template_name='clients/clients_details.html',
        context_object_name='client'
    ),
    name='details_client'
),
```

and specify the [**`slug_url_kwarg`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_url_kwarg) in the view:

```
class DetailClientsView(UpdateView):
    model = Clients
    slug_url_kwarg = 'client_slug'

    # …
```

In case the name of the `SlugField` in your *model* is not `slug`, you can set the [**`slug_field`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_field):

```
class DetailClientsView(UpdateView):
    model = Clients
    slug_url_kwarg = 'client_slug'
    slug_field = 'slugfield_from_model'

    # …
```

You normally do *not* have to use a `DetailView`, since the `UpdateView` will pass the object to the template as well. You thus can probably implement this as a "pure" `UpdateView`.